# Haskell: debug C function imported through FFI

Tags: debugging, haskell, ffi

I am importing some things in Haskell through the FFI, and would like to be able to debug them with lldb.  For example, I might have the following Haskell file (test.hs):

```
main = do
   foo
   return()

foreign import ccall "foo" foo :: IO ()
```

And the following C file (ctest.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(){
    printf("test\n");
}
```

I can then compile this with `ghc test.hs ctest.c`.  If I run the executable through LLDB, I can set a breakpoint at `foo`, however, it gives me only the assembly code, such as:

```
test`foo: ->  
0x1000019e0 <+0>: pushq  %rbp
0x1000019e1 <+1>: movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x1000019e4 <+4>: subq   $0x10, %rsp
0x1000019e8 <+8>: leaq   0x33eb31(%rip), %rdi      ; "test\n"
```

Is there a way to tell GHC to compile the C file I am importing through the FFI with `-g` so that I can get the debugging symbols?

Comment: Have you looked [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/options-phases.html#forcing-options-through)? optc might be what you are looking for.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!  If you want to move this down into an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GHC provides an interface to pass options to many internal components, including the C compiler. The option you're looking for is `optc`.

For example, you could write `ghc -optc -g Main`.

You can see a list of all similar options [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/options-phases.html#forcing-options-through).

Comment: I guess an equivalent way to this would be to have `cc-options : -g -O0` in the Cabal file?

Comment: That's just another way to pass options to GHC.